# Status bar in IOS weird behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uistatusbar

I have a splash screen that fades into the main screen with animation. I have set the UIstatusbar style to Light from General settings of the Project and also set "View controller-based status bar appearance" in info.plist to NO.

All the views and images start from y = 0, i.e the TOP. The status bar looks like this and i am not able to debug the reason.

[image: Status bar issue]

I have not written any additional code in view controller. Although i have tried the few of these but they dont seem to work

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

or making the statusbar hide = NO and setting style after animation end. None of these seem to work. Any pointers will be helpful.

[UPDATED]:
I have created a new view controller and embedded it in a navigation controller. It still happens on all the view controllers that i add new.

[image: View controller with new Navigation bar]

Comment: Have you tried to run the app in device?

Comment: Yes, it happens , but only in iPhone 6 and above. on iPhone 5S and below it looks fine

Comment: I think status bar not able to identify the width of the device. Have you set width 320 forcefully anywhere?

Comment: @iPhone: no. Actually even if i create a new view controller and just run it, i am facing the same issue. All the properties in attribute inspecter are inferred.

Comment: @ankit_rck i think you have selected 3.5 or 4 as Size while at design time.

Comment: Is it happening in all projects or just in one ?

Comment: Add Launch screen in your app for iPhone 6 and 6+ & Tell me the happy result... :) you may set nothing to Launch screen for test only

Answer (score 0):

Reset simulator settings that will do the trick

**Edit 1**

First clear that is it a code a error or SDK error if it is same in all project then it is SDK problem and if it is in only one project then it's a code error

Comment: Nothing happens, i am facing the same issue on iphone 6 device as well. Suprisingly it does not occur on iphone 5S and lower devices

Comment: what it looks like in landscape mode ?

Comment: just one project with this and new view controllers. Existing view controllers are working fine

Comment: I think your new view controller having same problem is child of `'this'` main controller, is it ??? have you tried creating new view controller that comes from `'working fine'` view controller ?? try to delete `"this"`  view controller and create once again if that works then note down all the properties and `"ctrl-z"` to get old view controller and make the note down change

Answer (score 0):

Status bar is displaying absolutely fine.. The issue is there with your view controller implementation..

Comment: Even if i create a new blank view controller and just run it, i am facing the same issue. All the properties in attribute inspecter are inferred.

Comment: Are you setting frame of window anywhere in your code?

Comment: Are you setting any static frame anywhere in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77682/discussion-between-nilesh-patel-and-ankit-rck).